# Vscode intellisense not working with pillow

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-imaging-library, intellisense

I can't seem to get intellisense to work on an Image object.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDEz.png)

I have tried resetting my settings and reinstalling.
The example is using pipenv but i have tested without it and it still does not work.

Comment: Which IntelliSense engine are you using? Jedi or Microsoft's engine? Have you tried both yet?

Comment: I have tried both, neither work.

Comment: Then it's simply possible neither of them can support it based on how Pillow works (e.g. complicated import setup, extension module are always hard, etc.). Best you can do is open issues on them.

Comment: Thank you it's good to know it's something to do with pillow and not something i'm doing wrong

Comment: Same problem. @ThePumkinMelon Would you mind sharing the issue link?